# How to generate dependency project jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, pom.xml

I have two maven java projects (lets say Project A and Project B). I have placed **Project B** as a dependency in **Project A**, since project A needs certain services from project B. I did like as shown below in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.projectB</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-projectB</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Everything looks good, but when I did `maven install` for **Project A** I got the below warning

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.projectB:api-projectB:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
```

which leads to build failure with a message like as shown below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project api-projectB: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.projectB:api-projectB:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.projectB:api-projectB:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

How can I generate the **Project B** jar upon doing `maven install` for **Project A**. I know that if I do `maven install` first for **Project B** and then do `maven install` for **Project A**  everything will work fine. But I want in the reverse way which I dont know how to do it

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Did you do maven clean install?

Comment: @Pradeep yes I did that as well

Comment: @Pradeep when I did `maven clean install` also I got `[WARNING] The POM for com.projectB:api-projectB:jar:1.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven resolves dependencies from two places only:

1. the local repository (usually in `~/.m2/repository`) or
2. a remote repository, be it internal to your company or external like [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/).

(In fact, [there are just these two types of repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).)

[There is a third option if you're working with Eclipse, where the [M2Eclipse plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) can resolve dependencies from the workspace while developing if the according project property is activated.]

So, to be able to resolve a dependency in another project you have to perform the following on the dependency's project at least once:

- `mvn install` (to the local repo), if needed just on your local machine
- `mvn deploy` (to a remote repo), if it is to be shared with others

To do this for all projects in one step you can create an [aggregator / multi-module](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) project like:

```
+- aggregator
   +- pom.xml
   +- A
   |  +- pom.xml 
   +- B
   |  +- pom.xml 
   +- C
   |  +- pom.xml 
   +- ...
   |  +- pom.xml 
   ...
```

where the aggregator's POM contains:

```xml
  ...
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>A</module>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
    <module>...</module>
  </modules>
  ...
```

and perform `mvn install` or `mvn deploy` on this aggregator project.

If you don't like the extra directory level the `aggregator` project introduces you can create it on the same level and use `<module>../A</module>`, and so on, in its POM.

And, BTW, `<scope>compile` is the default so you don't have to declare it explicitely. Remember: [Convention over configuration](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html). ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maven is saying it cannot find the jar for projectB. You need to `mvn install` projectB first.

If these are meant to be cohesive (i.e. they are really one build) then put them into one build with a [Maven multi-module build](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) which will then take care of doing the right things in the right order.

If they really are all seperate then, as someone mentioned, they should be kept in a central repository (e.g. Nexus, Artifactory etc) and built with CI (e.g. Jenkins) which can ensure your local build will always find a built copy of it's dependencies.